# How to trigger Glue Job using AWS GlueOperator

Tags: python, aws-glue, airflow

My Airflow script has only one task to trigger a glue job. I am able to create the DAG. Below is my code for DAG.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import AwsGlueJobOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


### glue job specific variables
glue_job_name = "my_glue_job"
glue_iam_role = "AWSGlueServiceRole"
region_name = "us-west-2"
email_recipient = "me@gmail.com"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'email': email_recipient,
    'email_on_failure': True
}


with DAG(dag_id = 'glue_af_pipeline', default_args = default_args, schedule_interval = None) as dag:
    
    glue_job_step = AwsGlueJobOperator(
        job_name =glue_job_name,
        script_location = 's3://my-s3-location',
        region_name = region_name,
        iam_role_name = glue_iam_role,
        script_args=None,
        num_of_dpus=10,
        task_id = 'glue_job_step',
        dag = dag
        )
   
    glue_job_step
```

When I run the DAG it fails and gives the below error:

> [2020-10-13 08:27:14,315] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-10-13
> 08:27:14,315] {glue.py:114} ERROR - Failed to run aws glue job, error:
> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Arguments,
> value: [], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
> [2020-10-13 08:27:14,315] {taskinstance.py:1058} ERROR - Parameter
> validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Arguments, value: [],
> type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'dict'> Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py",
> line 930, in _run_raw_task
> result = task_copy.execute(context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/glue.py",
> line 115, in execute
> glue_job_run = glue_job.initialize_job(self.script_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py",
> line 111, in initialize_job
> job_run = glue_client.start_job_run(JobName=job_name, Arguments=script_arguments)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 337,
> in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 628,
> in _make_api_call
> request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676,
> in _convert_to_request_dict
> request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line
> 297, in serialize_to_request
> raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report()) botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Invalid type for parameter Arguments, value: [], type: <class 'list'>,
> valid types: <class 'dict'> [2020-10-13 08:27:14,316]
> {taskinstance.py:1089} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a existing `GlueJob` try this,

```
glue_job_step = AwsGlueJobOperator(
        task_id = "glue_job_step",
        job_name = glue_job_name,
        job_desc = f"triggering glue job {glue_job_name}",
        region_name = region_name,
        iam_role_name = glue_iam_role,
        num_of_dpus = 1,
        dag = dag
        )
```

Remove `script_args` if there are no input arguments.

Comment: is it possible to use AwsGlueOperator against AWS Glue running in Docker container, eg. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/96? Do you have idea if that is possible or not?

Comment: If the job fails the operator retriggers it multiple times. How could I prevent that (and have the DAG fail if the job fails)?

Comment: You should set retries to 0 at task level. `retries=0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import AwsGlueJobOperator

region_name='<Region Name>' #Refer to Image below
glue_job_name='<Name of your Glue Job>'  #Refer to Image below

start_glue_job = AwsGlueJobOperator(
        task_id = "<some-unique-id>",
        job_name = glue_job_name,
        job_desc = "<Relevant description>",
        region_name = region_name,
        iam_role_name = "<glue_iam_role>",
        script_args={'--abc':'1','--pqr':'2'},
        num_of_dpus = 1,
        dag = dag
        )
```

[image: Name of Glue Job]

[image: Find your Region Name here]